# How to replace all the blanks within square brackets with an underscore using sed?

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

I figured out that in order to turn [some name] into [some_name] I need to use the following expression:

```
s/\(\[[^ ]*\) /\1_/
```

i.e. create a backreference capture for anything that starts with a literal '[' that contains any number of non space characters, followed by a space, to be replaced with the non space characters followed by an underscore. What I don't know yet though is how to alter this expression so it works for ALL underscores within the braces e.g. [a few words] into [a_few_words].

I sense that I'm close, but am just missing a chunk of knowledge that will unlock the key to making this thing work an infinite number of times within the constraints of the first set of []s contained in a line (of SQL Server DDL in this case).

Any suggestions gratefully received....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to the trickery needed:

1. Stop replacing when you reach a close square bracket (but do it repeatedly on the line):

   ```
   s/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/g
   ```

   This matches an open square bracket, followed by zero or more characters that are neither a blank nor a close square bracket.  The global suffix means that the pattern is applied to all sequences starting with an open square bracket followed eventually by a blank or close square bracket on the line.  Note, too, that this regex does not alter '`[single-word] and context`' whereas the original would translate that to '`[single-word]_and context`', which is not the object of the exercise.
2. Get sed to repeat the search from where this one started.  Unfortunately, there isn't a truly good way to do that.  Sed always resumes searching after the text that was substituted; and this is one occasion when we don't want that.  Sometimes, you can get away with simply repeating the substitute operation.  In this case, you have to repeat it every time the substitution succeeds, stopping when there are no more substitutions.

Two of the less well known operations in `sed` are the '`:label`' and the '`t`' commands.  They were present in the 7th Edition of Unix (circa 1978), though, so they are not new features.  The first simply identifies a position in the script which can be jumped to with '`b`' (not wanted here) or '`t`':

> ```
> [2addr]t [label]
> ```
>
> Branch to the '`:`' function bearing the label if any substitutions have been made since the most recent reading of an input line or execution of a '`t`' function.  If no label is specified, branch to the end of the script.

Marvellous: we need:

```
 sed -e ':redo; s/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/g; t redo' data.file
```

**Except** - it doesn't work all on one line like that (at least, not on MacOS X).  This did work admirably, though:

```
sed -e ':redo
        s/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/g
        t redo' data.file
```

Or, as noted in the comments, you could write three separate '-e' options (which works on MacOS X):

```
 sed -e ':redo' -e 's/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/g' -e 't redo' data.file
```

Given the data file:

```
a line with [one blank] word inside square brackets.
a line with [two blank] or [three blank] words inside square brackets.
a line with [no-blank] word inside square brackets.
a line with [multiple words in a single bracket] inside square brackets.
a line with [multiple words in a single bracket] [several times on one line]
```

the output from the sed script shown is:

```
a line with [one_blank] word inside square brackets.
a line with [two_blank] or [three_blank] words inside square brackets.
a line with [no-blank] word inside square brackets.
a line with [multiple_words_in_a_single_bracket] inside square brackets.
a line with [multiple_words_in_a_single_bracket] [several_times_on_one_line]
```

And, finally, reading the fine print in the question, if you need this done only in the first square-bracketed field on each line, then we need to ensure that are no open square brackets before the one that starts the match.  This variant works:

```
sed -e ':redo' -e 's/^\([^]]*\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/' -e 't redo' data.file
```

(The 'g' qualifier is gone - it probably isn't needed in the other variants either given the loop; its presence might make the process marginally more efficient, but it would most likely be essentially impossible to detect that.  The pattern is now anchored to the start of the line (the caret) and contains zero or more characters that are not open square bracket before the first open square bracket.)

Sample output:

```
a line with [two_blank] or [three blank] words inside square brackets.
a line with [no-blank] word inside square brackets.
a line with [multiple_words_in_a_single_bracket] inside square brackets.
a line with [multiple_words_in_a_single_bracket] [several times on one line]
```

Comment: Ahh, clever observation that `[a b c]` becomes `[a_b c]` after the first sub and thus can be processed recursively.  I was thinking along the lines of splitting `[stuff]` into a separate line, `y`ing those lines and then rejoining.

Comment: +1. Does it work on OS X to do this `sed -e ':redo' -e 's/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/g' -e 't redo'` instead of breaking it up on multiple lines?

Comment: @Dennis: yes (separating the sed script into 3 separate '-e' options works) - the key seems to be that the semi-colons screw it up somehow.  I'm not sure whether that's a bug in the MacOS X sed or whether it is more generally an issue with labels and branches.

Comment: Some versions of `sed` just don't do semicolons. What error message do you get when you try something simple like `echo hi | sed -e 's/h/H/;s/i/I/'`? Will it let you leave out the first (only) `-e`?

Comment: @Dennis: it was fine generating HI with and without the '-e'.  I've only noticed a problem with branches, and I don't use branching in sed scripts often enough to have run into the problem before.  I got no error message - it simply didn't do any substitutions (as if the whole of the command was treated as a single label operation).

Comment: Good catch on my not explicitly delimiting the search by the close square bracket, and well done too catering for my only wanting to do this on the first set of square brackets found on the line. Damn useful thing that t function - thank you so much for bringing it to my attention so thoroughly, succinctly, and clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier in a language like perl which has "executable" substitutions:

```
perl -wne 's/(\[.*?])/ do { my $x = $1; $x =~ y, ,_,; $x } /ge; print'
```

Or to split it up more clearly:

```
sub replace_with_underscores {
    my $s = shift;
    $s =~ y/ /_/;
    $s
}
s/(\[.*?])/ replace_with_underscores($1) /ge;
```

The `.*?` is the non-greedy match (to avoid slurring together two adjacent bracketed phrases) and the `e` flag to the substitution causes it to be evaluated, so you can call a function to do the inner work.

Comment: Why the name 'replace_with_slashes' given that you're replacing with underscores?

Comment: Obviously I meant *using* slashes to replace *with* underscores.  ;-)

Comment: Ben, whilst I appreciate the brevity and artistic elegance of your solution - unfortunately I had to give Jonathon the win because he nailed every one of my requirements (including using sed to do it). Thanks anyway for making the thread more interesting and generically useful.