# How can I learn the sed branches in Linux

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying but could able to understand the branches in `sed`.
Why do we need it and what purpose does it solve?

Example in this solution of removing the `\n` from the file, he uses:

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

I am not able to understand the labels.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-58).

Comment: i tried that before but could not get it. i don't know whats happening with his example. so many varibles , i am confused is that all one command or multiple commands

Answer (score 4):

It's a simple `goto`. You need to declare a destination label with `:label` or just `b` without a label to the end of the script. There are also the conditional jumps `t` and `T`.

In your exanple script, the "address" condition `$!` is true for all lines except the last (`$` means end of file, and `!` negates the condition). Thus there is a loop which reads the entire file into the pattern space, then falls through to the action after the loop, which substitutes all (internal) newlines (in some dialects of `sed`).

```
# declare label 'a'
:a
# append next input line to pattern space
N
# loop back to 'a' unless at end of file
$!ba
# substitute all newlines in pattern space
s/\n/ /g
# fall through to end: print the pattern space
```

I would agree that "branch" is a slightly misleading term but it has a long history; a better term might be "jump" or "go to".

Comment: Can you give any case where we need it and just simple example

Comment: I hope the description of your example script can help. If not, perhaps you can clarify what you still need help with.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of questions about `sed` where branches appear in the answer, including:

- [`sed` replace globally a delimiter with the first part of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566007/sed-replace-globally-a-delimiter-with-the-first-part-of-the-line/6566128#6566128)
- [How to remove characters from a word if they are also in the next word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349517/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-word-if-they-are-also-in-the-next-word-sed/9350980#9350980)
- [`sed`: hold pattern and rearrange line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266856/sed-hold-pattern-and-rearrange-line/6267824#6267824)
- [How to replace all the blanks within square brackets with an underscore using `sed`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503535/how-to-replace-all-the-blanks-within-square-brackets-with-an-underscore-using-se/4504131#4504131)

And I'm sure there are a lot of others.